# Getting different Symfony 2 applications to use the same session/login?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have four Symfony 2.1 applications, I want them to share the same sessions/login system so that logging in one gets you inside the others.

All applications are on the same domain and server, thus they get cookies properly. For some reason they still don't work exchangeable. They all have the same `secret` property specified in `properties.yml`.

The problem is that after logging into one, going to other applications require you to login again, and if you do that, then you get logged out of the previous application.

How do I get multiple Symfony 2.1 applications on the same server and domain to work with a single login?

Comment: You should be running the applications each as a bundle of one application, and then they can share the user system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should configure your session to point to the same storage location, which would be shared for all applications (in case if you use NativeSessionStorage, which is default).

```
framework:
    session:
        # ...
        save_path: "/your/shared/sessions/path"
```

By default `save_path` is set to `%kernel.cache_dir%/sessions` - which is relative to your applications.